# How can I get all versions of a specific list item using javascript?

Tags: javascript, version-history

I need to get the versions and its changes. It is possible using javascript client object model or REST?

Answer (score 1):

First get the list item object and try following:

```
var id = objListItem.get_item('ID');
var filePath = 'Path to current list/ListName/'+id+'_.000'

var web = objClientCtx.get_web();
var listItemInfo = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath)
var listItemFields = listItemInfo.get_listItemAllFields()
    objClientCtx.load(web);
objClientCtx.load(listItemInfo);
objClientCtx.load(listItemFields);
```

Every list item in sharepoint lists is like url and any list item will be represented as `path to site collection/Lists/list name/'+id+'_.000`.  id represents the current list item id

Get reference to individual list item info with the following code snippet
web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath) and execute the code

```
objClientCtx.executeQueryAsync(
    function (sender, args) {
        var fileVersions = listItemInfo.get_versions();
        objClientCtx.load(fileVersions);
```

`get_versions()` api will give all the versions of the current list item. Execute the query async again after calling the function get_versions().

`get_url()` will have the information regarding the version history number of the list item

Source

[How to get all versions of a SharePoint list using JSOM](http://techfindings-prem.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-get-all-versions-of-list-using.html)

Comment: If my site url is https://domain.com/, and my list is "Roteiros", filePath = ??

Comment: Go to view all site content, click the list and get the URL till `http://domain.com/Lists/ListName`

Comment: Hi, when I try to fetch get_createdBy from FileVersion object it returns SP.User object and when I try to fetch user title from SP.User object I get an error that Title is not initialize in the following manner:
while (objlistVersionEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var vItem = objlistVersionEnumerator.get_current();
            vItem.get_createdBy().get_title();
}
I even tried to load createdBy but failed.
Please help.

Comment: @DharamPadia can you try `.get_loginName()` instead of `.get_title()`

Comment: even .get_loginName() is not working.

Comment: That means the object is not returned successfully or is not loaded. Are you sure you have loaded the object and executeQuery doesn't throw any errors

Comment: SP.User Object is returned, even I tried to load this object but still I am getting same error. Yes, executeQuery doen't throw any errors. Its very strange. Any help would be appreciated.